# How to add units from a funtion to main lists

Tags: python, list, function

I have a problem where I need to classify species found in a forest to different lists. Here is my code so far:

```
# we assume these to be mutually exclusive lists
TREES = ["spruce", "pine", "birch", "maple", "willow", "oak"]
MUSHROOMS = ["false morel", "chantarelle", "milkcap", "funnel chantarelle", "brittlegill", "black trumpet", "forest lamb"]
FLOWERS = ["lily", "bluebell", "violet", "daisy", "red clover", "dandelion", "yarrow", "anemone"]

OTHER = 0
TREE = 1
MUSHROOM = 2
FLOWER = 3


def print_in_alphabetical_order(list_of_strings):
    list_of_strings.sort()
    for i in list_of_strings:
        print(i)

def classify_species(species):
    i = str(species)
    if i in TREES:
        return TREE
    elif i in MUSHROOMS:
        return MUSHROOM
    elif i in FLOWERS:
        return FLOWER
    else:
        return OTHER

def main():
    species = []
    lajike = str(input("Enter the species of the items you found in the forest. Stop with empty line.\n"))
    while lajike:
        species.append(lajike)
        lajike = str(input())
        end = "\n"
    print("Your finds in alphabetical order:")
    print_in_alphabetical_order(species)
    trees = []
    mushrooms = []
    flowers = []
    other = []
```

The "classify_species" function should be working fine. The problem is, how do I add the items from [species] list to the other lists in main function? They should be added using the "classify_species" function. I assume it has to be done with for-command but I don't know why. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please try to boil the code in your question further down to a [mcve]. If still relevant to the question then at hand, please also specify precisely what you want to achieve, e.g., do you want to only count specimens (by category of their species) or to store which species actually occurred? I.e., should the result be something like "3 trees, 5 mushrooms" or "2 oaks, 1 birch, 5 forest lambs"? Also try to show what you tried and explain how it failed (did you get error messages, is the result or other behavior of the code other than expected, etc.). See also [ask] in [help].

Answer (score 1):

I Assume you are asking how to filter the items from `species` list to all the other lists `trees, mushrooms, flowers, other`

```
# we assume these to be mutually exclusive lists
TREES = ["spruce", "pine", "birch", "maple", "willow", "oak"]
MUSHROOMS = ["false morel", "chantarelle", "milkcap", "funnel chantarelle", "brittlegill", "black trumpet", "forest lamb"]
FLOWERS = ["lily", "bluebell", "violet", "daisy", "red clover", "dandelion", "yarrow", "anemone"]

OTHER = 0
TREE = 1
MUSHROOM = 2
FLOWER = 3


def print_in_alphabetical_order(list_of_strings):
    list_of_strings.sort()
    for i in list_of_strings:
        print(i)

def classify_species(species):
    i = str(species)
    if i in TREES:
        return TREE
    elif i in MUSHROOMS:
        return MUSHROOM
    elif i in FLOWERS:
        return FLOWER
    else:
        return OTHER

def main():
    species = []
    lajike = str(input("Enter the species of the items you found in the forest. Stop with empty line.\n"))
    while lajike:
        species.append(lajike)
        lajike = str(input())
        end = "\n"
    print("Your finds in alphabetical order:")
    print_in_alphabetical_order(species)
    
    trees = []
    mushrooms = []
    flowers = []
    other = []

    for i in species:
        result = classify_species(i)
        if result == TREE:
            trees.append(i)
        elif result == MUSHROOM:
            mushrooms.append(i)
        elif result == FLOWER:
            flowers.append(i)
        else:
            other.append(i)
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much!

Comment: @KK If my answer is right pls mark it as correct by clicking on the tick mark that would help me a lot :)